# Unable to change "Reason" when adjusting state on work item type (TFS2013)

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I'll start with I'm new to customizing TFS and my TFS team project is a 99% vanilla template of `Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013`.  So I think my issue might be obvious to someone.  I'm also using VS PowerTools.

In a Scrum Task, when you change the status from **To Do** to **Done**, it defaults the Reason to "**Work finished**".  I'd like to be able to select alternative reasons, so I went to the transition from `To Do->Done` and added a new reason called "**Obsolete**", then saved it back to the server.  I've verified it shows up in the XML, etc.

[image: Work Item Type Workflow Screenshot]

When I change from **To Do->Done**, the reason is still greyed out and defaults to "Work finished"?

[image: Scrum WIT]

I created a new team project with the Agile 2013 template, and when you change the status from **New->Closed** you get the option to change the Reason to "Completed/Obsolete/Deferred/Cut".  This is the basic functionality I was trying to mimic.

[image: Agile WIT]

I don't see any unusual rules on any of the fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check out the XML for the form display you will see:

```
<Control FieldName="System.Reason" Type="FieldControl" Label="Reason" LabelPosition="Left" ReadOnly="True" />
```

If you change "Readonly='True'" to "Readonly='False'" you will get a pick-list when you change state.

Comment: Ah I thought I looked everywhere too!  Thanks